# Tinymce 5 inline - overflowing toolbar from content editable

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce-5

I have multiple tinymce which is inline.

But when I tried to edit, the toolbar overflows from the div.

Is it possible to not overflow the toolbar?

[image]

Here's my code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>
        Editor 1
      </h2>
      <div class="tinymce-inline" contenteditable="true">
        <p>
          This is my content 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <h2>
        Editor 2
      </h2>
      <div class="tinymce-inline" contenteditable="true">
        <p>
          This is my content 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tinymce-inline {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: 0;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 320px;
}
.tinymce-inline p { margin-top: 0; }
```

JS:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '.tinymce-inline',
  inline:true,
  height: 500,
  menubar: false,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
  ],
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: 'undo redo | fontsizeselect formatselect fontselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | image media | bold italic underline strikethrough | outdent indent | table forecolor backcolor link charmap'
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/17ks4nyr/1/

Comment: why not remove the inline:true, to make the toolbar part of the text area and it will inherit the css the toolbar will become visible at all times.

Comment: because I want a floating toolbar, that will be visible only when user starts editing